# Join field in modelbuilder won't work, but will manually

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, attribute-joins

I'm trying to do a 'join field' in a model. When I do the join simply not in a model, no problem.  When I try to use the 'join field tool' in a model, I get the `""<sheet>` does not have OIDs.

I have a very simple feature class in a GDB, trying to join with an Excel sheet. No problem to join. Only in the model.

Anyone got a clue?

Both files comply with the 'join rules' in file names etc.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your model?

Answer (score 2):

Import your excel spreadsheet into the same gdb as your feature class, this should fix the "does not have OIDs" error. Your join should then work in the model

Comment: The Excelfile doesn't have an column OID. If you add it and populate it with unique numbers (starting at 1) this error will be solved.

Comment: correct, importing it into the gdb will add the OID column

Comment: Glad to help! Accept the answer if your problem was solved :)